# Many to many relationships - Sql To Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Maybe it is a very simple solution, but I'm not getting the point. How can I write the following SQL using Linq?

```
SELECT 
[Source].[TaskId] AS [TaskId]
FROM   [dbo].[UserTask] AS [Source]
JOIN [dbo].[UserTask] AS [Target] ON [Source].[TaskId] = [Target].[TaskId] 
WHERE ([Source].[UserId] = 2) AND ([Target].[UserId] = 1) ORDER BY [Source].[TaskId] ASC
```

Consider that I have the simple table design

```
UserTask    
---------
userId
taskId
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var res = from source in UserTask
          join target in UserTask on source.TaskId equals target.TaskId
         where source.UserId == 2
            && target.UserId == 1
       orderby source.TaskId
        select source.TaskId;
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing the same !